# static fields getResource

Tags: java, swing, static, resources

everybody.

I am novice in Java and making training project with UI.
In process of trainings I decided to load icons from resources and to move its loading in the different class.
And got problem.
I really tried to find answers by myself but could not.Code bellow.

Main class

```
package scv.paul;
…
 /**
 * Create the application.
 */
public TestApp() {
    Logger.getLogger(loggerName).fine("Showing main window");
    initialize();       
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Test App");
    **frame.setIconImage( MyImages.appIcn.getImage());**//here try to load icon
```

And get exception:

*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError*

Utility class

```
package scv.paul;*
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class MyImages { 
public static final ImageIcon appIcn =  new ImageIcon ( MyImages.class.getResource ( "AppIcon.png" ) );
public static final ImageIcon BtnIcn =  new ImageIcon ( MyImages.class.getResource ( "OK.png" ) );
public static final ImageIcon exitIcn =  new ImageIcon ( MyImages.class.getResource ( "door.png" ) ); 
}
```

Images lay in "\bin" folder

I understand that the problem in the initialization of the static fields. But can’t understand reason.

I got this error if I call even such static field

```
public static final String imgPath = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir")+"\\img\\";
```

But I have no errors if I call in main class this static field

```
    public static final String imgPath = "c://myProjectPath//bin";
```

And I could not find how to work with resources in good stile. Where I could read it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use static variables for something like this. There is no need to keep a reference to the icon. Just read the Icon and add it to your button.

Just load the images in the constructor of your class (when you create your buttons). See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and working examples.

The tutorial will also show you how to better structure your code so the Swing components are created on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Keep a link to the tutorial handy for other Swing basics.

Comment: Thank You! I missed this tutorial. Now many things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Put you images in the directory of the projecet, e.g. where the bin and src folders are located.

Its best to use a static method to read in files aswell incase they fail. Say you your resource folder within the directory called resources, your code would look something like this.

```
public static ImageIcon makeImageIcon(String filename) {
    BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/" + filename));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ImageIcon(myPicture);
}
```

And then call this with the file name you want the same way you have done above.

```
public static ImageIcon image= makeImageIcon("myImage.png");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You! Previously I did something like.